# Angular material vertical slider

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I can't found any solutions for vertical slider in angular material so i decide to do this by CSS but it works not correct. Maybe someone had a similar problem?

**View**

```
<body>
    <md-slider name="slider" aria-label="slider" min="0" max="100" step="1"></md-slider>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
md-slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/65paR2aAOvPpWXr8BYZe?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

vertical slider is being added to material, you can wait or take a logic from [this](https://github.com/angular/material/commit/f1b7529b12ec5d4fb542cbe9e41bbcfe56bf6419)  build

You can also get repository from https://github.com/angular/material  and build it and then reference.

I am not sure for developer cdn availing this changes.

Comment: Thanks, i think that i can wait a bit especially if it was committed a day ago